Local environment for lambda in docker
My goal is to create a local environment for the project deployed in AWS lambda for the TS project. In my conception, it will be really close to the production of Lambda. I used this article: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-image.html
services:
  bulider:
    container_name: myproject-builder
    image: node:22
    working_dir: /usr/app
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/app
    command: bash -c "yarn install; yarn run dev-watch"
  lambda:
    container_name: myproject-lambda
    build: 
      dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile
      context: ./
    working_dir: /var/task
    volumes:
      - ./dist:/var/task
    ports:
      - "9000:8080"
    depends_on:
      - 'myproject-builder'

I created 2 containers. The first container builds in esbuild to dist dir with --watch flag. The second container runs public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs:22 image, and executes the code if the request is got via HTTP (POST: http://localhost:9000/2015-03-31/functions/function/invocations).
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs:22 
RUN npm install --global yarn

CMD ["index.handler"]

The problem is in watching the code. The second container has the current code in /var/task all the time. But after the first run, the container uses the same code because the code is stored in memory (please improve me if it isn't true), and refreshing the code in /var/task doesn't change the executed code. So I need to refresh the docker-compose after each change.
Maybe my conception is wrong and I shouldn't use it in this way. But my all projects always have the local environment in docker where I can develop my code. So I expect if I change the code, I will run it automatically.
Is there some solution that helps me?

You’re encountering a common issue when trying to mimic AWS Lambda in a local Docker environment. The problem arises because the Lambda runtime loads the code into memory on initialisation and doesn’t re-load it when the underlying files change, even if they’re updated via a volume mount. This behaviour is intentional and mirrors how AWS Lambda works in production, where code changes only take effect on a “cold start.”
If you want to use Lambda function locally, i suggest for you that you use AWS SAM CLI instead for local Lambda development, the AWS SAM CLI is built for this exact purpose and can handle hot reloading when your code changes.
You need just to replace your docker-compose by template.yaml that defines your Lambda functions. then just run:
sam build
sam local start-api --watch

This spins up a local API server that watches for changes in your code and automatically reloads the environment.
However, if you want to stick to docker-compose you can keep using it but you have to use nodemon utility, which will take care of watching any code change and restart the lambda runtime:
RUN npm install --global yarn nodemon

CMD ["nodemon", "--watch", "/var/task", "--exec", "node", "index.js"]


So you confirmed that the code is in the memory, thanks! I know nodemon, but I can configure it in this way that the second container (AWS) will be refreshed?

Yes, i didn't test it for the second container, but it should work

Ok, I ask because it doesn't work. The container shows: entrypoint requires the handler name to be the first argument. I think that this image public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs:22  expects to run index.handler - I added it to the nodemon - no changes...  I tested it with ENTRYPOINT etc. No works...

I checked what cmd is started for this container and I created a similar one: ENTRYPOINT ["nodemon", "--watch", "/var/task", "--exec", "/usr/local/bin/aws-lambda-rie /var/runtime/bootstrap aws-lambda-ric index.handler"]. Everything is started, the changes are detected, displaying is [nodemon] restarting due to changes... but running is old code. It looks like finally the lambda is not reset. Do you have any tips? Based on: https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-nodejs-runtime-interface-client/issues/9#issuecomment-1844445836

I think the issue stems from how the AWS Lambda Runtime Interface Emulator (RIE) and Runtime Interface Client (RIC) operate. While nodemon detects changes and restarts the process, the Lambda runtime itself is not resetting its internal state correctly. This is likely because nodemon is restarting the node process but not triggering a true “cold start” in the Lambda runtime.  so you need to explicitly clear the lambda cache

I couldn't find a way to reset/stop and clear the cache for AWS Lambda RIE :( This doesn't have a docs that include this information
